# background color on active icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an icon-bar similar to the one [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_bar.asp).

I'm using a script to show/hide content depending on what  tag is selected. My question is how can I give the icon a background color if one has been clicked? I've tried adding:

```
.icon-bar a:focus {
background-color: red;
}
```

to my CSS but it only flashes red then goes back to the original white.
code:

```css
.icon-bar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #777777;
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#box" title="Markets"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
  <a href="#box2"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
  <a href="#box5" title="List"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
  <script>
    $("a").click(function() {
      var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
      $(myelement).slideToggle(1);
      $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    });
  </script>

</div>
```

photo of my icon-bar for reference:
[image]

Comment: Add a class to the selected icon and then remove it when a different icon has been selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo-class `:focus` will only apply to elements currently in focus, so in other words; elements that are either clicked on or tapped on - but this state is ephemeral for anything other than an `input` field that isn't currently selected, so for generic elements, like say `a` tags in this case, it won't last.

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a form
>   input) that has received focus. It is generally triggered when the
>   user clicks or taps on an element or selects it with the keyboard's
>   "tab" key.

**Ref:** [:focus - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

**You'll require a javascript method for a lasting solution:**

```
   $('.icon-bar a').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('toggle-state');
      $('.icon-bar a').not(this).removeClass('toggle-state');
    });
```

This solution (demonstrated in the Code Snippet embedded below) is succinct and accounts for clicks *on active elements*, removing the active class and resetting to default styles.

```css
.icon-bar {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #777777;
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.icon-bar a.toggle-state {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#box" title="Markets"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
  <a href="#box2"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
  <a href="#box5" title="List"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
  
  <script>
    $('.icon-bar a').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('toggle-state');
      $('.icon-bar a').not(this).removeClass('toggle-state');
    });
  </script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to MDN documentation [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class indicates element that have current focus. It is, by definition, temporary status, but you want it to be permanent. Hence you need to create some CSS class that will contain styles for indication of "selected" icon on the bar and apply it upon click to clicked item. For example:

```js
$(".icon-bar a").on('click', function () {
  var $item = $(this);
  $item.siblings('a').removeClass('selected');
  $item.addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.icon-bar {
    width: 100%;

    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #777777;
}

.icon-bar a {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.icon-bar a.selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
    <a href="#box" title="Markets"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
    <a href="#box2"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
    <a href="#box5" title="List"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove 'addcolour' class on all siblings and then add it to the click element

jQuery

```
 $("a").click(function(){

     // remove class off siblings
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('addcolour');
     // add the class to this element
     $(this).addClass('addcolour');

     var myelement = $(this).attr("href")       
     $(myelement).slideToggle(1);
     $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();

 });
```

CSS

```
.addcolour {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the click function such that it will remove `background-color` from all `a`, then adding the color only to the targeted `a` as follows:

```js
$("a").click(function(){
    $('a').css('background-color','');
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle(1);
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    $(this).css('background-color','green');
});
```

```css
.icon-bar {
width: 100%;

overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid #777777;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #777777;
}

.icon-bar a {
float: left;
width: 20%;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px 0px;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
color: black;
font-size: 30px;

}

.icon-bar a:hover {
background-color: #e0e0e0;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-bar">
          <a href="#box" title="Markets"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
          <a href="#box2"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></a>
          <a href="#box5" title="List"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
        
</div>
```